# Assigning values to a list of variables

Tags: sml, smlnj

I want to input two lists of equal length and assign the values of one list to variables of another.
I want it to realize first list automatically as list of variables and second as values.
e.g.
I want to assign `[1,2,3,4,5,6]` values to the elements in the list of variables `[9,10,11,12,13,14]`, i.e.
1 as value of 9, 2 as value of 10 in the list.

```
exception error

fun assign([],_) = raise error
  | assign(_,[]) = raise error
  | assign(l::ls,b::ls) = (val l=b ; assign(ls,bs));
```

I know there are few a problems. First, functions should return value right? Any suggestion as to how I can handle that? By That I mean create a meaningful function that assigns values as desired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assigning values do not make sense on immutable types. I assume you would like to do this:

*There is a list of `int` `[1,2,3,4,5,6]` and a list of int [references](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs312/2008sp/recitations/rec15.html) which are initialized with default values  `[ref 0, ref 0, ref 0, ref 0, ref 0, ref 0]`. You would like to update references to `[ref 1, ref 2, ref 3, ref 4, ref 5, ref 6]`.*

You just need a small modification on your function:

```
fun assign([], []) = ()
  | assign(_, []) = raise error
  | assign(_, []) = raise error
  | assign(l::ls, r::rs)= (r := l ; assign(ls, rs))
```

The function returns `unit` and after calling `assign`, the list of reference holds new values.

However, for these scenarios with destructive updates, it is much better to use [array of values](http://www.standardml.org/Basis/array.html).

Comment: Thank you with the ref. I will go through it.

and, Sorry, I just realized that I cannot assign in this way: val 3=2; I had thought, here 3 is automatically converted to variable, which apparently is not the case. 

Ok, now, I have a list[a,b,c,d,e,f]. and another list [1,2,3,4,5,6]. I want to assign a=1,b=2,c=3,... Which as far as I know is not same as ref right? or is it?

Comment: You should use array; then you can write `update arr 2 2` (it means the 3rd element of `arr` is assigned to value `2`).